# An upper bound for the number of prime numbers in non-linear progressions

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $f(x)$ be  a non-linear polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the following sum $\pi_f(x):= \#\{y: y< x \text{ and } f(y) \text{ is prime} \}$.

Can we get an upper bound for $\pi_f(x)$?

Comment: Well, it is an open question whether $\pi_f(x)$ is at most a constant for all $f$ and $x$.  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can get sharp upper bound, matching (up to a multiplicative constant) the asymptotic predicted by the Bateman-Horn conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%E2%80%93Horn_conjecture). This is a standard (and almost the first) application of sieve methods. I recommend the books by Halberstam and Richert, or Cojocaru and Murty.